# Using a CABasicAnimation Cutting View In Half

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, clipping

So I want to rotate my UIView in what seems like 3D. I did a quick search and the inter webs said: Use Core Animation. So I took a look-see and I came up with this code to make my view rotate

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];
    animation.fromValue = @(0);
    animation.toValue = @(4 * M_PI);
    animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    animation.duration = 5.0;

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000;

    self.layer.transform = transform;

    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

The actual view rotates fine, but it cuts off half of the view. Heres a quick picture I made in photoshop to show what I mean[image]

I've did tons of searches for hours now, and I can't seem to figure out whats causing this.  Any help or input would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Heres how I created the view:

```
UIView* test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
        test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.view addSubview:test];
```

After trying it on a view made in interface builder, it works fine, but I need to make these programatically.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. How is the red view created and added to its superview. Does it have constraints to its superview?

Comment: @rdelmar They're just added with [addSubview] into the superview, there aren't any constraints or anything going on with it.

Comment: Since your code worked for me (with a storyboard added subview), you should show how you created and add that red view. I don't think the problem is with the animation code.

Comment: Hmm... I tried adding the view the same way, and it still works fine for me (I made a subclass of UIView, and put the animation code inside didMoveToSuperview

Comment: I put the code in the same method, and that didn't work. What version of Xcode are you using? The code worked fin on a view I made in interface builder

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: @rdelmar Thats so odd, Im using the same version of Xcode. What am I doing so wrong that this just doesn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62713/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-bluespud).